# NSFetchedResultController with SUM

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

How should I fetch data by first attribute and sum the values of the second?

By simple fetch I have:

[image]

But I need to display the same **ZINGREDIENT** only in 1 row and sum the values of **ZCOUNT**:

[image]

It is like:

```
select ZINGREDIENT, sum(ZCOUNT) 
from Table
group by ZINGREDIENT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the quite simple NSFetchRequest version:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [object managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest* request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Join"];
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"count"];
    NSExpression* expr = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];
    NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [expressionDescription setName:@"count"];
    [expressionDescription setExpression:expr];
    [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType];
    [request setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"ingredient"]];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"ingredient",expressionDescription]];
    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* rez = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Comment: it was a difficult version )) Thank you @Mark! I got an **array** with 2 items [5, 400]. Everything alright! But than, how to access to other attributes? For example, like **array.ingredient.name**?

Comment: Result array contains dictionaries and each of them has two keys 'count' and 'ingredient'. Under 'ingredient' key you can find object of 'Ingredients' type, so you can simple access to its name.

Comment: really ) thanks, Mark! I have noticed you memorized my work direction.. Can you give me some advice how can I operate with this result list in future. So **join** entity contains an attribute **inCart** too. This attribute is BOOL: YES - "need to buy", NO - "don't need". I have added predicate "inCart == 1" to your simple fetch. In future I'm going to add a possibility to remove items from this list. In my example, ingredient with ID==20 is in 3 recipes, how should I turn "inCart" to NO for the 3 items (in Join) at once?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand your questions. Could you rephrase them in more descriptive way.